# Вывод сумы в sqlite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Нужно вывести сумму столбцов в конце списка. Пытался использовать `TOTAL()` но не вышло - просто получаю одну строку с суммами.Сам запрос выполняю так:

```
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
            "SELECT %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            ", %q"
            " FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q = %q AND %q BETWEEN '%q-%q-%q' AND '%q-%q-%q';"
            , SCHEME_REPORT_TIME
            , SCHEME_HISTORY_RECIPE_TITLE
            , SCHEME_HISTORY_FULL_NAME
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_1
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_2
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_3
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_4
            , SCHEME_REPORT_BITUMEN
            , SCHEME_REPORT_MP
            , SCHEME_REPORT_DUST
            , SCHEME_REPORT_CELLULOSE_1
            , SCHEME_REPORT_MIXING_TIME
            , SCHEME_REPORT_TEMPERATURE
            , SCHEME_REPORT_TEMPERATURE_BITUMEN
            , SCHEME_REPORT_ASPHALT
            , TABLE_REPORT_NAME, TABLE_RECIPE_OPERATOR_HISTORY, SCHEME_HISTORY_ID, SCHEME_HISTORY_BIND_ID, SCHEME_REPORT_TIME
            , startYear, startMonth, startDay
            , finishYear, finishMonth, finishDay);
```

**UPD:** 
С использованием UNION:

```
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
                "SELECT %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                ", %q"
                " FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q = %q AND %q BETWEEN '%q-%q-%q' AND '%q-%q-%q'"
                " UNION ALL "
                "SELECT TOTAL(%q)"
                     ", TOTAL(%q)"
                     ", TOTAL(%q)"
                     ", TOTAL(%q)"
                     ", TOTAL(%q)"
                     ", TOTAL(%q)"
                     ", TOTAL(%q)"
                     ", TOTAL(%q)"
                     "FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q = %q AND %q BETWEEN '%q-%q-%q' AND '%q-%q-%q';", ...);
```

Но получаю ошибку: *`SQL error: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял вам нужен `SUM()`.

Comment: на сколько я знаю TOTAL() и SUM() отличаются только тем что первый возвращает значение с плавающей точкой а второй целочисленое значение.Мне нужен именно TOTAL().

Comment: да, так и есть. Теперь понял вопрос. Что мешает сделать один запрос на результаты, а второй на сумму?

Comment: tcpack4, хотелось бы все сгрупировать сразу.

Comment: тогда подойдет UNION, он склеит результат двух запросов.

Comment: как раз смотрел в эту сторону, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: кол-во полей должно быть таким же.

Comment: к примеру (SELECT id, name, price) UNION (SELECT '' as id, '' as name, TOTAL(price))

Comment: спасибо, все заработало.